# Latex first page prints: "ï»¿"

Tags: windows, compiling

It's my first time posting so if I omit anything that I shouldn't have please let me know.

I'm using TeXnicCenter, when I view my output after building my first page is blank apart from: "ï»¿".

[image]

A little research (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255993/how-do-i-remove-i-from-the-beginning-of-a-file) showed this has something to do with BOM? I don't really understand, I only started using Latex a few hours ago and I just can't get rid of this.

(I've omitted the code I'm using as I had the same error when trying to view a template.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Sorry for misplacing this initially!

It's irritating that there isn't a more reasonable solution, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Using UTF-8 and activating it inside TexnicCenter *and* inside the Document (via inputenc) should do the trick.

Comment: I found a way to not get the error. I had been inputting a titlepage, if instead of that I just paste the titlepage into the main it all works fine.

That will do for me, thanks for your help all.